# Running google tests in batches

Tags: googletest

My existing code base consists of 500+ unitests, and due to resource constraints in test environments running them all in a single process fails with memory problems.
Is there a tool to run the tests in batches. 
Eg.
MyTests --gtest_list_tests
1A.A
...
1000A.A

Tool MyTests --batch-count 10
will first run the first 10 in a single process. 
After process stops it will start the next 10 in another process.
Manually adding a filter is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Google Test has [support](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#distributing-test-functions-to-multiple-machines) for sharding tests. You can specify the total number of shares you want to split your tests to and the index of the current shard to run in environment variables.